# Why do `Object` and `Function` have the same prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)` in JavaScript？

What is the purpose of this design？

Comment: The question could use `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` and its intent would be the same. The fact that `__proto__` is not standardized is irrelevant.

Comment: @IHateLazy—the fact that `__proto__` is not standardised is very relevant. It isn't supported by all browsers in use and has only recently been added to the draft for ECMA-262 ed 6 (or Harmony or ESNext or whatever it's called at present). Remember that ed 4 was never standardised and there was an awful lot in ed 4 that was removed before ed 5 (aka ES5, the most recently standardised version).

Comment: @RobG: It's not relevant to the question being asked, unless OP is actually comparing `undefined` to `undefined`, which would seem terribly unlikely.

Comment: @IHateLazy—the original comment has been deleted so I can't comment on what was said, only what has been responded to. Given that the OP seems a bit confused about properties, it's useful to provide information beyond strictly answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

The [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) of an object indicates the prototype that that object is inheriting.

Since `Object` and `Function` are both functions, they both have the same prototype, namely, `Function.prototype`.

Comment: And to be clearer, this is because you are looking at the constructor functions Object.prototype is different then Function.prototype and those are respectively equal to the `__proto__` properties of normal objects and functions.

Comment: @missingno—another way to say that because both a functions, their internal `[[Prototype]]` references the same object, i.e. `Function.prototype`.

Comment: This discussion would be helped if `[[Prototype]]`/`__proto__` and `.prototype` didn't share the same name.

Comment: How can this be possible ? Why is `Function.prototype` equal to `Function.__proto__` ? So this means Function inherits from itself.

Comment: @Taurus: Yes; `Function` is itself a function.